# ffmpeg How to create a video from N images applying zoom efect to each image

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images

I'm trying to create a video from a group of images with the same time for every photo and applying a zoom effect to each image.

I found a solution to create the zoom effect for one image,

> ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image_1.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125" -c:v libx264 -t 5 -s "800x450" zoomout.mp4

But I don't know how to apply it to several ones.

Comment: Apply it to a sequence: `ffmpeg -i image%d.jpg` or if they are not numbered serially, pipe them `cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i - ...`

Comment: I tried with   

ffmpeg -y -i %04d.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125" -c:v libx264 -t 20 -s 1920x1080 zoomout.mp4    

And doesn't work. It shows the first image during 5 seconds and then the third with a few frames of the second. (with 5 images)

Comment: Works here. Share full log.

Comment: There aren't any error in the log and it's too large for a comment. Could you write here your command to double check I don't miss anything?

Comment: I copy-pasted your command in the comment and only changed the input pattern. Which version of ffmpeg?

Comment: ffmpeg version 3.4.2-2

Comment: same problem here, I am using windows